# C inline Assembly generating unhandled exception

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

So I have this function written in C

```
int transform ( char * p )
{
    if(*p!='-'){
        return 0;
    }

    p++;
    if(*p == 'a')
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(*p == 'b')
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And I tried to translate it to inline assembly ia32 like this

```
    int trasform ( char * p )
    {
        int result; 
        _asm
        {
            mov eax, p
            mov ebx, 0
            mov bl, [eax]
            cmp bl, '-'   ;
                jne invalid
                mov bl, [4*eax]
            cmp bl, 'a'
                jne isB
                mov result, 1
                mov eax, result
            jmp out
    isB:
            cmp bl, 'b'
                jne invalid
                mov result, 2
                mov eax, result
            jmp out 
    invalid:
            mov result, 0  
            mov eax, result
    out: ; end

    }
    return result;
}
```

When I have the function written in C it works perfectly in Visual Studio, but when I change it to inline assembly and execute the code, I get an Error saying

> Unhandled exception at  0x774e15ee in proyect.exe : 0xC0000005:  Access violation reading location 0x01745388.

Does this problem has to be with the code or is it problem of visual studio?

I debugged my code and found that error is in this line

```
mov bl, [4*eax]
```

Comment: How is `transform` called? I question the legitimacy of dereferencing `p` after `p++`.

Comment: @Bathsheba In the main function I receive as a command argument -b or -a so I call transform function to see if the argument I received is valid. arg = argv[3]; and then int op = transform(arg);

Comment: Visual Studio lets you debug your code by executing one instruction at a time (press F11 if I recall correctly). This will point at one particular instruction that generated the exception. Please [edit] your post and write what this instruction is - this is very important info for solving your problem!

Comment: @anatolyg Ok, I have already done this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the debugger indicates, the problem is in this instruction:

```
mov bl, [4*eax]
```

Looking at the C code, its intention is to load the second byte of the string into `bl`. The pointer to the first byte is `eax`, so the pointer to the second byte is `eax+1`. That is, the proper command is

```
mov bl, [eax+1]
```

Alternatively, you could do that with two instructions:

```
inc eax
mov bl, [eax]
```

This is more in line with C code:

```
p++;
if (*p == ...)
```

but does the same.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> mov bl, [4*eax]
>  cmp bl, 'a'
> ```

The idea is to advance the pointer in `EAX`. No need to multiply it!

```
inc eax              ;ptr++
mov bl, [eax]
cmp bl, 'a'
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to read the byte after the '-', which will be at `eax+1`, not at `4*eax`.